Creating 3D shapefile using QGIS of cube with co-ordinates taken from underlying OSM map
Background to the problem
Within QGIS I have two shapefiles representing a roads layer and a buildings layer (both taken from OSM).

I now need to create a third 3D shapefile representing the airspace above the roads and buildings. I need to create it as a layer of the above in order that it picks up the same 2D co-ordinates plus height. In other words, I need to create it as a layer along with the two layers already mentioned [This is to satisfy the requirements of GAMA Platform where I shall use the three files].
I need to be able to export the shapefile with a third dimension - it is not enough that I can simply render it in 3D (or 2.5D) within QGIS.
What I envisage is a cube sitting on the above road / building layers. The two current layers (roads + buildings taken from OSM) have a CRS of EPSG:4326  WGS 84. The new cube would cover the entire road network and would have height of 500 meters.
Can you give a really simple step by step guide as to produce and export a 3D cuboid shapefile for use elsewhere?

I have edited the original query as requested.

Do you need the actual 3D space ? Otherwise you might want to use Qgis's 2.5D option to display what you need

While shapefiles can support multipatch geometries, which are required for true 3D support, you seem to be using 2D with Z values (aka 2.5D), which is not 3D.

Kaspser - the 2,5D only renders it within QGIS. I am trying to create a 3D shapefile for use outside QGIS.

Vince - is it possible to create a 3D object, with geo-referenced data as well as height within QGIS and export it as a shapefile, maintaining its three dimensions?

In my view, the problem here is the "step by step guide". GIS SE is not a tutorial site, but a problem-solving one. Each one of those tasks is a robust question unto itself, so you still have a focus issue.  The most common comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Please [Edit] the Question to address these.
